# Send PDF from Angular to .NetCore server?

Tags: asp.net, .net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

So, I create a PDF using jsPDF and want to send it to the .NetCore server. I convert the file to binary string on the front-end and convert it back to the PDF through C#. When the service calls the controller, the program hangs because it can't find data in the passed parameter.

Here's my component

```
this.eServ.addPDF(this.generatePdf()).subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
      });


  generatePdf() : string {
    const doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.text("somestuff", 40,30);
    var binary = doc.output();
    return btoa(binary);
  }
```

Service

```
addPDF(pdf: string) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(pdf))
    return this.http.post('/api/email/upload', pdf, { headers: this.headers });
  }
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public Task<IActionResult> upload(string mailMessage)
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("upload"); 
            var pdfBinary = Convert.FromBase64String(mailMessage); //here's the error 
            using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
            using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(fs))
            {
                writer.Write(pdfBinary, 0, pdfBinary.Length);
                writer.Close();
            } 
           return null;
        }
```

The error is in the controller and complains that the mailMessage is empty so it cannot convert.
On the front-end, the binary prints just fine something off when sending to the controller.
Another note: the routes and the other functions work fine and the "upload" get's printed to the console.

Also, I'm even open to other ways to send the PDF to the server, not necessarily want to stick to the binary method!

Comment: Have you considered sending the PDF inside a [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) instance and subsequently parsing it appropriately in the corresponding WebAPI method? I've used this approach when wanting to forward binary data from a client to the server successfully in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say, create a JS and a TS object, say Email, and add a property, say attachment, and then send and receive the email object. Check if you can print the email object that you pass.

TypeScript

```
emailObj: Email = new Email();//put this during class initializations
this.emailObj.attachment = this.generatePDF()
this.eServ.addPDF(this.emailObj).subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
      });
```

So, the service will be

```
addPDF(emailObj: Email) {
    return this.http.post<Email>('/api/email/upload', pdf, { headers: this.headers });
  }
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public Task<IActionResult> upload([FromBody] Email eObj)
        { 
    Console.log(eObj.attachment);

}
```

Comment: Yeah, I guess that would be a way around. I'm still not sure why the string object doesn't work, but this seems to do the trick. Thanks.